# Distributed Tensorflow save fails no device

Tags: tensorflow

I am following the example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/distributed/) to create a distributed tensorflow model with a parameter server and n workers. I do not have any GPU, all work is distributed on CPU

In the chief worker, I want to save my variables every some steps, but invoking the saver results in the following exception :

```
Cannot assign a device to node 'save_1/RestoreV2_21': 
Could not satisfy explicit device specification 
'/job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0' because no devices matching that 
specification are registered in this process; available devices: 
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0

[[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_21 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_INT32],
_device="/job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0"](save_1/Const, 
save_1/RestoreV2_21/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_21/shape_and_slices)]]
```

I tried :

```
server = tf.train.Server(cluster,
                         job_name=self.calib.params['job_name'],
                         task_index=self.calib.params['task_index'],
                         config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
```

I am using a supervisor :

```
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(
                         is_chief=is_chief,
                        ...)
```

and creating my sesion as follows :

```
sess = sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target)
```

but I am still having the exact same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line in the error message:

```
available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
```

...suggests that your `tf.Session` is not connected to the `tf.train.Server` you created. In particular, it seems to be a *local* (or "direct") session that can only access devices in the local process.

To fix this problem, when you create your session, pass `server.target` to the initializer. For example, depending on which API you are using to create the session, you might want to use one of the following:

```
# Creating a session explicitly.
with tf.Session(server.target) as sess:
  # ...

# Using a `tf.train.Supervisor` called `sv`.
with sv.managed_session(server.target):
  # ...

# Using a `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`.
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(server.target):
  # ...
```

Comment: thanks. I am creating the session as you say. I add it in the question

Comment: I updated the question to make it clear I already do that in the session creation